# why sound appears between VCC and GND pins in esp8266 module?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

When I use esp8266 as **STATION** mode and connect a speaker between VCC(3.3v) and GND pin a sound appears like "doop doop". what is this sound?
I test this in version 01 and 12 of esp8266 module and this appear in both versions.
maybe you ask me why I connect speaker to this pins. problem is that when I use pwm of esp8266 for playing a sound, this sound ("doop doop") appear to it also.
What is problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: sounds like your power supply is weak. it might also have trouble driving an 8-ohm load (400+ma) plus the MCU. more capacitors would help as well.

Comment: Maybe the ESP resetting? It is really not a good idea, to connect a speaker like this.

Comment: No .I use different power supply and different battery. I use high pass and low pass filter but it does not fix yet. Also I use capacitor between VCC and GND. I'm wondered now.

Comment: If reset occurred LED must be on in a moment. I'm sure reset does not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "noise" and is to be expected. Wi-Fi devices are generally very electrically noisy - and the ESP8266 is no exception.

Comment: I think noise sound is irregular but this sound is regular and periodic.

Comment: As regular and periodic as the transmission of packets over WiFi?

Comment: No. when I set esp8266 as station mode, without any connection and sending and receiving packet this problem occur

Comment: Just because *you* aren't sending packets doesn't mean packets aren't being sent. Wi-Fi is complex. There's constant chatter between stations and the AP.

Comment: It's true. your mean is packets send in environment such as mac address or Host name?

Comment: And others. Key exchange, etc. Lots of things happening. And it all needs lots of current - and that makes noise on the power.

Comment: it's not a way for removing this noise from power? I see some project with Node MCU that playing stream audio without this noise. should I use additional hardware?

Comment: You can't "get rid" of the noise. You just have to block it from going where you don't want. Filters, capacitors, inductors, etc. They all help.

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/filtering-wifi-noise

Comment: thank you so much.